# Is there any module for event based programming in Python

Tags: python, event-handling

Can we do event driven programming in Python. If we can, can some one tell which modules (standard or 3rd party modules) to look at. I hope I am not asking a ambiguous question, I am new to Python so please don't mind.

Comment: You might want to consult Google. Many good results there, e.g. http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7871

Comment: Thanks Danilo. Twisted looks exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing that came into my mind when I saw your post was Twisted.
Ofcourse it depends on what your goal is, but you should check it out
[here](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)